# phpMyAdmin wrong configuration on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm running Debian Sid (headless) with phpMyAdmin 4.2.2deb1.

When I log in on phpMyAdmin I see the following message:

```
The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click here.
```

So I click the link and I see this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] ... not OK [ Documentation ]
Saving Query-By-Example searches: Disabled
```

The [`Documentation`](https://u5r.nl/phpmyadmin/url.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.phpmyadmin.net%2Fen%2Flatest%2Fconfig.html%23cfg_Servers_savedsearches) link is broken.

I've editted `config.inc.php` once to add a reCAPTCHA key, so I compared it to the latest file, which is still the same (except for the reCAPTCHA key of course).

I can't find anything on Google except for [this](http://o6asan.com/blog-e/2014/05/14/phpmyadmin-4-2-0-is-released/).

The `pma__favorite` and `pma__savedsearches` tables were already created (they're empty, but do have a structure). In my `config.inc.php` I've created the following entries:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = ‘pma__savedsearches’;
```

But I'm still getting the error.

Does anyone know what else could be wrong?

---

**Update**

It seems the phpMyAdmin documentation has been updated (the link is not broken anymore), but it's not really useful.

Also, it seems everything is working (I now see 2 'bubbles' on the top left with `Recent` and `Favorites` and the tables now contain data) but the error is still showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved it myself.

After checking the table was already there, the `phpmyadmin` user had permission to use it and some other things I saw a little difference between my configuration entries:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite'; // Good entry
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = ‘pma__savedsearches’; // Bad entry
```

Note the difference between `‘` and `'`.

I changed it and now the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Found someone that had a similar issue. Try the solution explained in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261858/the-phpmyadmin-configuration-storage-is-not-completely-configured).

Comment: Thank you, but that's not my problem. I only have one error. Everything seems to be working as it should now but the error is still showing.